# vtk to unity, problems with colors

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, vtk

I am trying to get some vtk data to a format that is readable by unity, eg. obj. I have tried vtkOBJexporter but have so far failed to export colors in my object. I also tried ply to go from vtk via blender to unity but I again had troubles getting colors exported.
Any ideas what is the best approach for that?

Comment: Does the color show in blender?

Comment: no, do not show up in blender, meshlab or paraview

Comment: To be able to help you, please add more details to your question. What is the file type of your data? The obj file might have references to other files for colors, materials, textures etc. So the obj file might not contains the color data. You may include some images in your question.